# An error occured while download build-essential on Ubnutu 18.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

i'm using Ubuntu 18.04LTS on Windows.

when i `sudo apt-get install build-essential` ,it tells me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                            libc-dev
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:5.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.11) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and aslo accroding some passages, i aslo add these to `source.list`:

```
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
```

but the error still happens, i don't know how to fix it.Please help me .Thanks

Comment: "xenial" = Ubuntu 16.04. You followed an old, obsolete, not applicable advice. The first thing is to reverse what you did. Then run `sudo apt update` and check for other errors. Please [edit] to update your question accordingly.

Comment: Also fix the issue, "you have held broken packages." You can do this from terminal (https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-fix-broken-packages) or using Synaptic Package Manager (https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/fix-broken-packages-on-ubuntu/).